# Wildcard routing not working in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-artemis

I am using Apache Artemis as the message bus and JMS to listen and send messages to the message bus. I have a use case where I want to listen to all queues that matches a pattern(Eg the topic starts with xxxx). According to what I have explored we can use wildcard routing to do that. 
http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html

I have put the following in my broker.xml

```
<wildcard-addresses>
    <routing-enabled>true</routing-enabled>
</wildcard-addresses>
```

I am using the following code to send a message to a queue:

```
@Component
@EnableJms
public class Producer {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("address.client1")
    String destinationQueue;

    public void send(String msg){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, msg);
    }

}
```

Below is my Listener that should listen to all the queues that starts with **address.**

```
@Component
public class Consumer { 

    @JmsListener(destination = "address.>")
    public void receive(Message message){
        if(message.getPayload() instanceof String){
            System.out.println("Recieved Message: " + message.getPayload().toString());
        }else {
            System.err.println("Message Type Unkown !");
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not able to receive the message that we sent from the sender to the receiver code. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You've disabled the routing and you're wondering why it doesn't work? `<routing-enabled>false</routing-enabled>`

Comment: Sorry my mistake in the question

Comment: I have it has true

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked in your question is for ActiveMQ 5.x, not ActiveMQ Artemis. The ActiveMQ Artemis documentation for wildcards is [here](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-syntax.html).

The problem with your consumer is that you're using the wrong syntax. It is using `address.>`. You can either change the wildcard syntax configuration in Artemis, e.g.:

```xml
<wildcard-addresses>
   <routing-enabled>true</routing-enabled>
   <any-words>&gt;</any-words>
</wildcard-addresses>
```

Or you can use the functionally equivalent syntax from the default Artemis configuration, i.e. `address.#`.