# Problem with wildcard routing in Artemis v2.17.0 and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-artemis

I am having a listener problem with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 while using Spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE.
I used Spring Boot Artemis dependency to send messages to multiple **queues** via:

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, message)
```

I am sending the message to 3 different queues:

- queue.test1.event
- queue.test2.event
- queue.test2.event

On the listener side I  am using the wildcard to read from all of the queues, like:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "queue.#")
    public void receiveMessage(String event) {
      //....
    }
```

But I am not getting anything.
The web console shows I have 4 queues (3 mentioned above with another one as `queue.#`) and the `WildcardRoutingEnabled` is set to `true` as well.

[This official Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-syntax.html) explained the Artemis wildcard pattern, and I am following it. Don't know why it doesn't work.

PS: I have used the ActiveMQ wildcard pattern with ActiveMQ before and it worked perfectly with Spring boot ActiveMQ dependency(used this listener: `@JmsListener(destination = "queue.>")`)

I also commented on [Wildcard routing not working in ActiveMQ Artemis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802860/wildcard-routing-not-working-in-activemq-artemis/68578685#68578685) but since the original post was old, I decided to repost the new issue here. Let me know if I have to do revert it.

Comment: Add what point are you creating your consumer? Is it before or after you send the messages?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Let me try that one, but for ActiveMQ it didn't matter. I created my listener afterward and it was able to listen to all queues with wildcards.

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram, You were right. Thanks a lot. 
But it is still weird because I cannot guarantee the sequence of the listener or producer.

Comment: You can pre-create your resources in `broker.xml` to avoid the race condition between your consumer(s) and producer(s).

Comment: I cannot because I am working in a dynamic multi-tenant environment and each Queue represents a tenant and they are dynamic.
Thanks a lot  for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are seeing the expected behavior. This is because the feature you're using is a [wildcard **address**](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-routing.html). In short, any messages sent to a matching address will also be routed to the wildcard address (and any queues bound to that address according to their semantics (i.e. anycast or multicast)).

However, I believe the wildcard address hasn't yet been created when you send your messages (since you haven't created your consumer yet) so there is no way for those messages to be routed to it.

FWIW, you can see this feature in action in the `topic-hierarchies` examples which ships with the broker in the `examples/features/standard` directory.